# Which custom groovy code written in upload programatically summary report to MySQL data base in jmeter

Tags: mysql, groovy, jmeter

I want the results to be uploaded after the test, how to configure summary report listener in csv file, after the test completion upload MySQL db, what custom code is used uploading programmatically

Answer (score 0):

1. When you [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like

   ```
   jmeter -n -t testplan.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```

   you're getting .jtl results file
2. In order to get the "Summary Report" from the .jtl results file you can use [JMeter Plugin Command Line Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line/) like:

   ```
   JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv summary.csv --input-jtl result.jtl --plugin-type SynthesisReport
   ```
3. At this stage it will be more convenient to use MySQL [LOAD DATA statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) like it's described in [Import CSV File Into MySQL Table](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/)

If you still want to use Groovy - take a look at [Creating/Inserting data](https://groovy-lang.org/databases.html#_creatinginserting_data) chapter of [Working with a relational database](https://groovy-lang.org/databases.html) page of Groovy documentation